# How to test market data parsing program

Tags: c++, performance, fix-protocol

I'm developing a program to receive and parse market data from a exchange. What's the best way to test my program during the development? The data was sent via a multicast socket, but I don't have access to the socket before the program's correctness and performance is "fully" tested.

The test methods I came up so far:
1. use the TCP recovery channel provided by the exchange (not suggested by the exchange since it's not for TEST)
2. save some data in binary format, then set up a multicast test channel locally to simulate the actual environment

Any better ideas?

Comment: This sounds like a case for using a [mock object](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) to abstract away the socket stuff during testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot really test "performance" until you are connected to the exchange - most exchanges provide a development connection (some will charge for this service) Typically the traffic levels aren't anywhere near production, but it's a good environment to test your program. I would check with your account manager to see how you can get access to the test environment.

You can *validate* your parser using canned data, but any performance numbers from this are effectively micro-benchmark numbers - hence take with a *large* pinch of salt.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing out the high traffic level in production!